# Building a primary key with Json columns

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I am trying to set a unique constraint across rows, in which some of them are JSON data types. Since there's no way to make a JSON column a primary key, I thought maybe I can hash the desired columns and build a primary key on the hash. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE petshop(
name text,
fav_food jsonb,
md5sum uuid);
```

I can do the following:

```
SELECT md5(name||fav_food::text) FROM petshop;
```

But I want that to be performed by default and/or with a trigger which insert the md5 sum into the column `md5sum`. And then build a pkey on that column.

But really, I just want to know if the JSON object is unique, and not restrict the keys in the JSON. So if anyone has a better idea, helps!

Comment: Hmm. What kind of data is in that JSON? Are you sure it would make for a good primary key?

Comment: Does your JSON contain an attribute that makes it unique? In that case you could create a unique index on that attribute value.

Comment: The JSON does not contain an attribute that makes it unique and the keys in the JSON doesn't have to be the same for each row.

This table I have is a table for some analysis output.  The JSON is used to store initialization parameters which may contain different subsets of parameters.  I want to only store unique sets of initialization parameters, since the output is deterministic.